# Moving a UIButton programmatically?

Tags: user-interface, uibutton, cgrect

Right now I want to move the position of the button dependant if it is an iPhone 5 screen or not, but I am having trouble figuring out how to move the button, right now I have an "if statement" that can figure out if it is an iPhone 5 or not, but I don't know how to move my button inside the statement. Take a look at my code.

.h

```
-(IBAction)randomButton;
//the button I want to move
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {

    //I don't know how to move the button in here.

    }

}
```

Comment: You're making work for yourself if you're moving buttons programmatically just to adapt to a different screen size or aspect ratio. This is exactly what the springs-and-struts (pre-iOS 6) and autolayout (iOS 6 and above) mechanisms are for. If you're starting from scratch, learn autolayout rather than springs-and-struts; it's the way Apple wants you to go. Try checking out this introduction: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 0):

The right place to put this programmatic layout is either in a `layoutSubviews` method (if, for example, the view controller's root view is a custom subclass) or in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your view controller class.  In either of those methods, you can set the button's position and size by modifying its frame, like:

```
_theButton.frame = /*whatever*/
```

If you want to change the button's position without modifying the button's size you can adjust the button's `center` instead of its `frame`, but *usually* if you're doing programatic layout you want to set both the position and size in the same place.

Comment: So ive put the viewDidLayoutSubviews method but when i put _myButton (_randomButton) in there it says theres an undeclared identifier.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have an instance variable for `_randomButton` in your view controller class.  You should post your view controller's `@interface` section so we can see how your button is declared.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more complex layouts, you can also use 2 XIB files, one for iPhone 5 and one for iPhone 3/4. I typically do that as I can always see what it will look like without guessing or trial and error.